# Populate values using optionCollection Tag in struts1

Tags: struts-1

I have an arraylist which contains {1,2,3,4,5} as objects. i want to show these values in dropdown select box. how do i achieve it. how to map with value and label property?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <%
    for (int j = 0; j < arrayNew.size(); j++) {
    %>

        <%
            if ("dropDown") {
        %>
        <%
        if (counter == 0) {
        %>
        <select name="serveyTakerValue">
            <%
                counter++;
            }
            %>
                 <option value=<%=arrayNew.get(j)%>><%=arrayNew.get(j)%></option>

            <%
                }
            %>
 <%
  }
  counter = 0;
 %>
       </select><br><br>
```

Try this will solve your problem. 
NOte: `<select name="serveyTakerValue">` and `</select`> must be called once. That's why counter is being used here in this code. Assume arrayNew be your ArrayList.